# Java stored procedure batch with multiple OUT params

Tags: java, stored-procedures, transactions, batch-file

I'm using Oracle DB.

And I need to call stored procedure sequentially for 1000 times. This stored procedure has several in params and out params. 
Currently I'm doing it under one transaction. 
Simply using java's for-each loop and using Spring's StoredProcedure within of it. This transaction takes about 4 seconds. And it's not very cool. I need to speed-up this transaction time. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a wrapper stored proc that calls all the other ones, inputting all the data to the wrapper proc as a hashmap, or something similar (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oraarr.htm#g1072333), storing the output in a cursor and returning it back out to Java.  Call the wrapper from Java.  You then let the DB do all the heavy lifting and the entire job runs in one DB tx.

Answer (score 0):

You could batch up the queries (using "in" if it is 1000 non predicable IDs) and return a cursor instead of a couple of out params each time? Of course, this won't be as easy if your in parameters differ per call.

Comment: yes, i have different input params. So, seems this solution is not acceptable in my case.